# How can I re-send member activation email

Tags: members, email, activation, member-management

Is it possible to re-send activation emails? I am looking at a member profile in the back-end who is "pending". For some reason they haven't received the initial activation email and I would like to send it to them again.

Also, when they try to login, it tells them that they need to activate there account. I would like to have a link in there so they can re-send the activation email to themselves.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can resent the activation link from Member Administration area of that member. While going to that you can see "Resend Activation Email" link at left bottom.

> Also, when they try to login, it tells them that they need to activate
>   there account. I would like to have a link in there so they can
>   re-send the activation email to themselves.

Could you share more info about this point.

Comment: Is it possible for a user to trigger or request the activation email to be re-sent?

Comment: I don't think there is any such feature in EE. It can be developed with some custom small plugin... like giving user facility to input his email address to request activation link and an email notification can be sent to admin so that admin can re-send the activation email from the control panel.